# Trying to find a way to transfer Spring boot user to a /home or /index after succesfull login

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

this is a general quick question. As my native language isn't english I have trouble searching up on google what I need.

**The situation:**
I have created a spring application which I can access through "localhost:8080" and which uses spring security and after the login it shows the index.html I have put in the main/resources/static folder.

**What I am trying to do:**
I want the homepage to be and automatically transfer to "localhost:8080/home" or "localhost:8080/index" instead of just being "localhost:8080"

My controller class :

```
package com.lukas.ramonas.cms.DAO;

import com.lukas.ramonas.cms.Model.User;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.Collection;

@Controller // This means that this class is a Controller
@RequestMapping(path="/home") // This means URL's start with /home (after Application path)
public class MainController {
     // This means to get the bean called user_tableRepository
    // Which is auto-generated by Spring, we will use it to handle the data

//    @GetMapping("/index")
//    public String index() {
//        return "index";
//    }

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository UserRepository;

    @PostMapping(path="/add") // Map ONLY POST Requests
    public @ResponseBody String addNewUser (
            @RequestParam String name,
            @RequestParam String username,
            @RequestParam String password,
            @RequestParam String email,
            @RequestParam Collection roles,
            @RequestParam Boolean confirmed) {
        // @ResponseBody means the returned String is the response, not a view name
        // @RequestParam means it is a parameter from the GET or POST request

        User n = new User();
        n.setName(name);
        n.setUsername(username);
        n.setPassword(password);
        n.setEmail(email);
        n.setRole(roles);
        n.setConfirmed(confirmed);
        UserRepository.save(n);
        return "Saved";
    }

    @GetMapping(path="/all")
    public @ResponseBody Iterable<User> getAllUsers() {
        // This returns a JSON or XML with the users
        return UserRepository.findAll();
    }


}
```

If any extra info or code is needed I am happy to provide.

Answer (score 0):

`@RequestMapping` does **accept multiple mappings**, not just a single one:

You can add like this:

```java
@GetMapping(value = {"/", "/home", "/index"})
public String index() {
    return "index";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, although there is no change to the application with this input it seems. Still after localhost:8080/login it goes to localhost:8080 and the address localhost:8080/home and localhost:8080/index gives me a

 Whitelabel Error Page

Comment: You need to remove `@RequestMapping(path="/home")` or you can try a new controller where this is not there.

Comment: Can you post the part where the user logs in?

Answer (score 0):

per default spring security will return you back to the original forbidden url you tried to access.

So for instance, if you try to access `http://locahost:8080/foobar` and you are unauthenticated you will get a `302 Redirect` to `/login`, when successfully authenticated, you get a `302 Redirect` back to `/foobar`.

If you wish to override this behaviour you can do this in several ways.

You can either set the `successForwardUrl` in your `HttpSecurity` config:

```
http.formLogin()
       .successForwardUrl("/foobar")
```

or you can implement the interface `AuthenticationSuccessHandler`

```
http.formLogin()
    .successHandler(customAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
```

and build a custom redirect response:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(
        HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response,
        Authentication authentication
    ) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // Mutate the response here
    }
}
```